# Is the size of any set constructible from the set of natural numbers?

Tags: set-theory

I like to prove that for any set there exists a set of simple graphs that have the trivial automorphism group and such that there are no homomorphisms between them. I have an idea how to prove this, but this only works if the following holds:

If we start from the set of natural numbers, for any set $S$ we can construct a set $N$ from the natural numbers such that $|S|<|N|$, where the construction only includes taking the power set and unions. By this I also mean unions of infinitely many sets, so $B$ is also included in this example.

$$A_0:=\mathbb{N}$$
$$A_n:=\mathcal{P}(A_{n-1})$$
$$B=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$$

Is it possible to use this, and if so, do i need the MK or NBG extensions, or hypotheses such as the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: You can't get any strongly inaccessible cardinals this way. So you'll need the _negation_ of a large cardinal axiom...

Comment: @ZhenLin Even if there are inaccessible cardinals, by taking union of length that inaccessible cardinal, then inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ is a subset of $V_\kappa$.

Comment: @William The unions are indexed over $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Nothing in the question suggest that the union must be countable. I originally thought this as well. Anyway, if it was restricted to only countable union, then one could not obtain any strong limit cardinal of uncountable cofinality, which alway exists in $ZFC$.

Comment: Read the displayed formulae!

Comment: @ZhenLin He is only saying $B$ is an example of such a set. In his example, he only take countable union. The only phrase that indicate what sort of union he wants is the line "By this I mean unions of infinitely many set, so B is included in this example ..."

Comment: @ZhenLin I indeed only included this as an example, unions of larger sets are also included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in $ZF$ in particular using the foundation and replacement axiom.

Define $V_0 = \emptyset$. If $V_\alpha$ has been defined let $V_{\alpha + 1} = \mathcal{P}(V_\alpha)$. If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $V_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\gamma < \alpha} V_\gamma$. Let $\text{WF} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \text{Ord}}V_\alpha$.

So starting with $\emptyset$, $V_{\alpha + 1}$ formalizes taking power sets. For limit $\alpha$, $V_{\alpha}$ formalizes taking the union of all sets already constructed in this way.

Using the axiom of foundation, it can be shown that $V = \text{WF}$. Therefore every set $S \subseteq V_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$.